# Vagrant guests can't access each other on private_network

Tags: vagrant, private-network

I'm trying to 2 Vagrant VMs to communicate through a private network, but I must not be doing something right, because neither can ping the other on the ip address I specify.  Here's my Vagrantfile configuration:

```
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "nrel/CentOS-6.5-x86_64"

  config.vm.define "vm1" do |box|
    box.vm.hostname = "vm1"
    box.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
      v.memory = 512
      v.name   = "vm1"
    end
    box.vm.network :private_network, :ip => "10.0.2.51"
  end

  config.vm.define "vm2" do |box|
    box.vm.hostname = "vm2"
    box.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
      v.memory = 512
      v.name   = "vm2"
    end
    box.vm.network :private_network, :ip => "10.0.2.52"
  end
end
```

But here's what I get when I try to ping vm2 from vm1:

```
[vagrant@vm1 ~]$ ping 10.0.2.52
PING 10.0.2.52 (10.0.2.52) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.0.2.15 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.2.15 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.2.15 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

I checked `ifconfig` on each machine, and they look like:

vm1:

```
eth2 ... inet addr:10.0.2.51  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0 ...
```

vm2:

```
eth2 ... inet addr:10.0.2.52  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0 ...
```

I can't even ping or ssh into either of the guests from the host.
Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: Btw, my environment is a Win 7 host with Vagrant 1.7.2 and VirtualBox 4.3.20.  The VMs are CentOS 6.5

Comment: I do multiple VMs just like that, also using private networking, and it works for me. I suspect it may depend on the netmask setting of the host. If you search google for something like "vagrant private network netmask", you'll see a bunch of troubleshooting that may be helpful. I use a Mac for the host and do sometimes need to do a full computer restart when the network seems to go off into the woods, but that's not too often.